# How drag child elements with parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm crating a drag and drop library that creates node dinamically and each node/row can create children.

My problem is that when I dragg a node with children only drag parent and children doesnt show dragging.

So, my only option is to make that children doesnt show when dragg.

I've tried different ways, I've read how to do it but I can do it possible.

How can I do to show children when dragg the parent???

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
    generatePortalBranch,
    replaceBranch,
    addBranchInTree,
    removeBranchInTree,
    findBranchInTree,
} from "../../utils/portal";

import { IBranchProps, IBranch } from "../main/interfaces";

import { getAncestor } from "../../utils/hierarhcy";

export function PortalBranch({
    id,
    collapsed,
    parentId,
    level,
    title,
    tag,
    draggable,
    editable,
    updateName,
    checkbox,
    checked,
    children,
    branch,
    branchs,
    maxPortalChildrens,
    onUpdateBranchs,
    numBranchs,
    onUpdateNumBranchs,
    renderPortalBranch,
    removeBranchWithChildren,
    onUpdatePortalCheckBoxChildren,
    onShowModal,
}: IBranchProps) {
    let timeout: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> = setTimeout(() => {}, 0);
    let lines: Array<Element> | null;
    const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState<boolean>(checked);
    const [dragging, setDragging] = useState<boolean>(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setIsChecked(checked);
    }, [checked]);
    const onChangeName = (event: any) => {
        const newTite: string = event.target.value;
        const updatedBranch: IBranch = Object.assign({}, branch, {
            title: newTite,
        });
        let updatedBranchs: Array<IBranch>;
        if (parentId === undefined) {
            const index = branchs.findIndex((b: IBranch) => b.id === id);
            updatedBranchs = Object.assign([], branchs, {
                [index]: updatedBranch,
            });
        } else {
            updatedBranchs = replaceBranch(branchs, updatedBranch);
        }
        onUpdateBranchs(updatedBranchs);
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            onChangeStatusUpdateName();
        }
    };

    const constructScaffold = (space: number) => {
        // // Construct the scaffold representing the structure of the tree
        const fatherAncestor = getAncestor(branchs, level - space, parentId);
        const ancestor = getAncestor(branchs, level - space - 1, parentId);

        let lineClass = "go-lineBlock";

        if (level === space) {
            lineClass = "go-lineBlock go-lineBlock--corner";
        } else if (
            (fatherAncestor &&
                ancestor &&
                fatherAncestor.children.indexOf(ancestor) !==
                    fatherAncestor.children.length - 1) ||
            (!fatherAncestor &&
                branchs.indexOf(ancestor) !== branchs.length - 1)
        ) {
            lineClass = "go-lineBlock go-lineBlock--vertical";
        }
        return <div key={`branch-${id}-${space}`} className={lineClass}></div>;
    };

    const onChangeStatusUpdateName = () => {
        const updatedBranch: IBranch = Object.assign({}, branch, {
            updateName: !updateName,
        });
        const updatedBranchs: Array<IBranch> = replaceBranch(
            branchs,
            updatedBranch
        );
        onUpdateBranchs(updatedBranchs);
    };

    const onRemoveBranch = () => {
        const updatedBranchs: Array<IBranch> = removeBranchInTree(
            branchs,
            branch.id
        );
        onUpdateBranchs(updatedBranchs);
    };

    const onCreateChildren = () => {
        if (maxPortalChildrens === level + 1) return;
        let newBranch: IBranch = generatePortalBranch(numBranchs, checkbox);
        newBranch = Object.assign({}, newBranch, {
            level: level + 1,
            parentId: id,
            position: children.length,
        });
        const updatedBranchs: any = addBranchInTree(branchs, newBranch);
        onUpdateBranchs(updatedBranchs);
        onUpdateNumBranchs(numBranchs + 1);
    };

    const onSetCheckBox = () => {
        onUpdatePortalCheckBoxChildren(branch, !isChecked);
    };

    const onShowTags = () => {
        onShowModal(branch);
    };

    const onHandleDragStart = (event: any) => {
        setDragging(true);
        const target: any = event.target;
        event.dataTransfer.setData("id", target.id);

        const branch: IBranch | null = findBranchInTree(parseInt(target.id), branchs);
        let items: Array<HTMLElement> = [];
        if (branch && branch.children.length > 0) {
            branch.children.forEach( (child: IBranch) => {
                const item: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById(String(child.id));

                if (item) items.push(item);
            });
        }

        timeout = setTimeout(() => {
            if (items.length > 0) {
                items.map( (item: HTMLElement) => item.style.display = "none");
            }
            target.style.display = "none";
        }, 0);

        lines = [...target.querySelectorAll(".go-lineBlock")];
        lines?.forEach((line: Element) =>
            line.classList.add("go-lineBlock--hidden")
        );
    };

    const onHandleDragEnd = () => {
        setDragging(false);
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    };

    const onHandleOver = (event: any) => {
        event.preventDefault();
    };

    const enableRemove: boolean = removeBranchWithChildren
        ? true
        : children.length > 0
        ? false
        : true;
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div
                className={`complete-branch ${collapsed ? "collapsed" : ""} ${
                    dragging ? "dragging" : ""
                }`}
                id={String(id)}
                draggable={draggable}
                onDragStart={onHandleDragStart}
                onDragEnd={onHandleDragEnd}
                onDragOver={onHandleOver}
            >
                {[...Array(level + 1)].map((_level, index) =>
                    constructScaffold(index)
                )}
                <div className="go-checkbox" id={String(id)}>
                    {checkbox && children.length > 0 && (
                        <label
                            className="go-react-checkbox mx-2"
                            id={String(id)}
                        >
                            <input
                                id={String(id)}
                                type="checkbox"
                                checked={isChecked}
                                onChange={onSetCheckBox}
                            />
                            <span className="checkmark" id={String(id)} />
                        </label>
                    )}
                </div>
                <div id={String(id)} className="go-react-branch my-1">
                    {!tag && (
                        <div id={String(id)} className="branch-move">
                            <i className="icon-th" id={String(id)} />
                        </div>
                    )}

                    <div id={String(id)} className="branch-info">
                        <div id={String(id)} className="branch-title">
                            {updateName ? (
                                <input
                                    id={String(id)}
                                    type="text"
                                    value={title}
                                    onChange={onChangeName}
                                    onKeyDown={onChangeName}
                                />
                            ) : (
                                <label id={String(id)}>{title}</label>
                            )}
                        </div>
                        <div id={String(id)} className="branch-icons">
                            {maxPortalChildrens !== level + 1 && (
                                <i
                                    id={String(id)}
                                    className="icon-plus-squared-alt"
                                    onClick={onCreateChildren}
                                />
                            )}
                            {!tag && editable && (
                                <i
                                    id={String(id)}
                                    className="icon-pencil"
                                    onClick={onChangeStatusUpdateName}
                                />
                            )}
                            {!tag && editable && enableRemove && (
                                <i
                                    id={String(id)}
                                    className="icon-trash-empty"
                                    onClick={onRemoveBranch}
                                />
                            )}
                            {!tag && editable && (
                                <i
                                    id={String(id)}
                                    className="icon-tags"
                                    onClick={onShowTags}
                                />
                            )}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            {children &&
                children.length > 0 &&
                children.map((child: IBranch, index: number) => {
                    return renderPortalBranch(index, child);
                })}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.go-react-tree {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 350px;
    height: 100vh;
    color: $color-background-light-1;
    background-color: $color-background-dark-2;
    overflow: hidden;

    &__create-button {
        max-width: 150px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        cursor: default;
    }

    i {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

.go-react-branches {
    width: 100%;
    height: 95%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: baseline;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.go-react-portal-branches {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 95%;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
}

.placeholder {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 60px;
    height: auto;
}

.dragging {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    min-height: 60px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: It would be great if you can add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).